# small fopen/fwrite issue. Suggestions please

Tags: c

Can anyone tell me what's wrong with this code? I'm getting a seg fault. I'm trying to read just the first line of a file into a newly-created file.

```
char *buffer;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  FILE *source = fopen(argv[0], "r");
  FILE *destination = fopen("destination", "w");

  fgets(buffer, 500, source);
  fwrite(buffer, 1, sizeof(buffer), destination);

}
```

Comment: Did you consider to ask warnings & debug info when compiling (e.g. with `gcc -Wall -g`) and to use the `gdb` debugger (assuming a Linux system) ? You should ask the compiler to help you as much as it can, and you really should learn to use your debugger when coding in C.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You haven't allocated anything for `buffer`.

Change:

```
char *buffer;
```

to

```
char buffer[500];
```

As your code is right now, `buffer` is just an uninitialized pointer. Attempting to dereference it will cause undefined behavior. (and seg-fault in your case)

---

Alternatively, you can dynamically allocate memory for `buffer`:

```
buffer = (char*)malloc(500 * sizeof(char));
```

but you should remember to free the memory later on:

```
free(buffer);
```

If you go with this latter method, the code will look like this:

```
char *buffer;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  FILE *source = fopen(argv[0], "r");
  FILE *destination = fopen("destination", "w");

  //  Allocate
  buffer = (char*)malloc(500 * sizeof(char));

  fgets(buffer, 500, source);
  fwrite(buffer, 1, 500 * sizeof(char), destination); //  Fixed here

  //  Free memory
  free(buffer);

  //  Don't forget return value
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Your buffer has no size - its a pointer to char array. You need to malloc some space to read into

Comment: Also, `sizeof(buffer)` is the same as `sizeof(char *)` which is not what you want. You want to write out as many bytes as you read in, not as many bytes as the buffer occupies.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz Right. Thanks I missed that.

Answer (score 0):

You should allocate memory to store the data. It can be either statically allocated using `arrays` or dynamically allocated using `malloc()`

```
#define BUFLEN 50

/* static allocation */    
char buffer_array[BUFLEN];

/* dynamic allocation */
char * buffer_ptr = NULL;
if ((buffer_ptr = (char *)malloc((int)sizeof(char) * BUFLEN)) == NULL) {
    printf("ERROR: unable to allocate memory \n");
    return 0;
}
```

and here you can pass either `buffer_array` or `buffer_ptr` to `fgets()` and `fwrite()`

But all the dynamically allocated memory must be `free()`'ed as follows.

```
free(buffer_ptr);
```